# laravel observers are not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to listen to model events using [laravel observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) .The problem is when i submit my form (update or creating new records), nothing happened at all .Do i miss something ?

**app.php**

```
  'providers' => [
        ...
         App\Providers\CasesManagerServiceProvider::class,
]
```

**CasesManagerServiceProvider.php**

```
class CasesManagerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot( )
    {

        Cases::observe(CasesObserver::class);
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }

}
```

**CasesObserver.php**

```
class CasesObserver
{
    private $cases;

    public function __construct(Cases $cases){
        $this->cases = $cases;
  }


    public function creating(Cases $case)
    {
        dd('creating');
    }

    public function saved(Cases $case)
    {
        dd('saved');
    }

    public function updating($case)
    {
        dd('updating');
    }
    public function updated($case)
    {
        dd('updated');
    }
}
```

**Cases.php**

```
class Cases extends Model
{
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified_at';

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'updating' => CasesObserver::class,
    'updated'  => CasesObserver::class,
    'creating' => CasesObserver::class,
    'saved'    => CasesObserver::class,
];
}
```

Comment: Have you registered your service provider in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @sam yes, and i have update it in my question

Comment: Do you added `$dispatchesEvents` to model?

Comment: @Nikita yes , i have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i have found my answer . All the problem was when I added 
`use app\Observers\CasesObserver;` in `CasesManagerServiceProvider.php` instead of `use App\Observers\CasesObserver;` .
Yes the Camel case of `App` was the problem, so i changed to App and all things are working fine now.

Answer (score 13):

for me, the problem was registering observer in the `register() method!`
so when I put it in the `boot() method` every thing worked well! the reason is the order of running methods in service providers which are mentioned [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49782464/10079059)

hope be useful

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a misuse of Composer and Laravel themselves.

You should inform them that you have added some files and configurations:

To autoload the files:

```
composer dump
```

To reconfigure the cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this help you too!

Comment: This didn't seem to answer his question but I've come across this issue numerous times and a good ol' composer dumpautoload always saves the day!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use $dispatchesEvents in your case. You should try to remove `$dispatchesEvents` from model, and remove `__constructor()` from CasesObserver.

Comment: I tried your solution but i got the same result , nothing happened

Comment: Do you try to dd() on boot() method in service? Before Cases::observe() call;

Comment: You can't name a model with (case) because its a reversed keyword in php , i will try another model

Comment: Are your laravel.log empty? With this case of course.

Comment: Do you tried to log in the methods of observer instead dd()
I mean `\Log::info('bla-bla');`

Comment: I reproduce your case on my application. Everything works fine. Check what all of the classes which you use are in use section. I create simple Observer class with one saved() method and added to AppServiceProvider my `Model::observe(Observer::class);`

Comment: yes i have tried your solution and it worked for me in a new project , i don't know till now how to fix this in the current project

Answer (score 2):

Not possible according to the documentation. When issuing a mass update or delete query via Eloquent.

[image: look at the picture]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30802854)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have to add a `HasEvents` trait to your model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use HasEvents;

    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*In Laravel 9.x*, Once you have all your observers ready and created in the eventServiceProvider, you must validate the way you're updating the model.

Remember, mass updates, as described in the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-updates), won't trigger the Eloquent model events like 'saving', 'saved', 'updating', and 'updated'. For instance:

```
Cases::where('id', $id)->update(['field', 'new-value']);
// This type of mass update will not trigger model events 
//Observer will be ignored.
```

As a workaround, you can instead retrieve the instance first and then update the field manually. This method will fire the relevant Eloquent model events. Here's an example of how you can accomplish this:

```
$case = Cases::find($id);
$case->field = 'new-value';
$case->save(); // This will trigger the observer events
```

Note: This could be a cause. After trying several times, I had to read the documentation to realize why it wasn't executing.